# Can't set checked attribute in radio button (radio button inside table)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I tried setting radio button checked to `checked="checked"` however this does not seem to work . 
I have tried using

1. $(id_radio).prop('checked',true);
2. document.getElementById("id_radio").checked = true;
3. document.getElementById("id_radio").checked = true;
4. document.getElementById("id_radio").checked;
5. $(id_radio).attr('checked',checked);

But none of them seems to be changing the attribute of `checked` to `checked="checked"`

Below is my code
js_file.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("document").on("click",".class_radio3",function(){

  var id_radio=$(this).attr('value');
  $(id_radio).prop('checked',true);
  console.log(id_radio);
});
});
```

My code for creating table

```
    <br>
    <p class="uk-text-primary uk-text-bold"><u> General Message </u></p>
    <table class="uk-table uk-border-rounded uk-grid-width-* uk-panel-box uk-text-justify" border="1">
        <!--create top table -->
        <tr> <!--tr defines a row --> <!-- define row 1 -->
            <th class="uk-width-1-10"> Recipient </th> <!-- th defines a header cell--> 
            <th class="uk-width-1-3"> Message </th>
            <th class="uk-width-1-10"> Action </th>
            <th class="uk-width-1-10"> Default message </th>
        </tr>
         <!-- row 2 : display results onwards and creates dynamically -->   
        <!-- input fields at the bottom -->


            <?php
                include "../connect.php"; 
                $get_data2admin = $db->query("SELECT ID,message,user FROM test_table_1 WHERE user='General'");


            if( $get_data2admin->num_rows >0 ){ //if selected rows is more than zero
                while($row_msg = $get_data2admin->fetch_assoc()){

                    $row_msg_id=$row_msg['ID']; //$row_msg['ID'] directly using it wont display in id tag attribute
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row_msg['user']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row_msg['message']. "</td>";

                    ?>

                    <td><a href="#" id="<?php echo $row_msg_id; ?>" class="delete_button uk-text-danger">Delete</a></td>

                    <?php 
                    if($row_msg['user']=='General'){
                        echo "<td>"."<input class='class_radio3' type='radio' name='name_radio2' value='$row_msg_id' checked=''/>"."</td>";

                    }
                    else{
                        echo "<td>"."-"."</td>"; 
                    };

                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }

        ?>
</table>
```

What could be the issue? Any insight/solution? Am a beginner in PhP any advice would be helpful. Thank you

> Note
>   Its printing out the right id selected so i dont think its selection issue

A sidenote: another issue if i try using e.preventDefault at

```
$("document").on("click",".class_radio3",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```

The radio button becomes un-clickable.Why is that so?

> Update 1: Picture of what is the issue
>   [image: Picture of issue]

[image: console]

Comment: is this print or not ??
 console.log(def_radio);

Comment: @HEMANTSUMAN typo, i just corrected it but yes it does print the right #id selected

Comment: Please include the straight HTML - what the client-side sees (PHP is server-side only).  You can see this via page source.

Comment: @allicarn i Have already included the table which is what the client would see. The server side mysql connection works fine as other data can be inputed and deleted

Comment: why u get the value of radio button just do that
$(this).prop('checked',true);

Comment: @HEMANTSUMAN just tried using $(this).prop('checked',true) doesn't change checked="" to  checked="checked"

Comment: no need to set two time checked,,, checked="checked" it work also with one checked just remove checked="" in your HTML,

Comment: @peekaboo a client does not see any PHP - that is compiled on the server side and delivered to the client as pure HTML.  Check the page source and you will see the client does not see any of your PHP code or variables.

Comment: I tried to dry run your code and it is absolutely nonsense. The way I see it, you are trying to _check_ a link: `.class_radio3` is a radio button, `var id_radio=$(this).attr('value')` (probably) gives you a number, `$(id_radio)` is definitely a smell since (i) it is missing `#` (ii) even if you add then it matches a link element which cannot be checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of issues here... one is that only one radio can be checked per group - i.e. radios with the same "name".  Having `checked=""` is the same as `checked="checked"` - the absence of the attribute altogether is the "unchecked" state.

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Group 1</h1>
  <p><input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" checked="checked" />1</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" checked="checked" />2</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="group1" value="3" checked="checked" />3</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="group1" value="4" checked="checked" />4</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="group1" value="5" checked="checked" />5</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Group 2</h1>
  <p><input type="radio" name="group2" value="1" checked="checked" />1</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="group2" value="2" />2</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="group2" value="3" />3</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="group2" value="4" />4</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="group2" value="5" />5</p>
</div>
```

Secondly, in your code, you are saying (if I understand what PHP is outputting correctly), onclick of this input (radio), set the thing with an id that is the same as my value's property "checked" to true.  That thing with an id is the `a` tag.  An `a` tag does not have this checked property.  See below where I'm setting its background to red (via a class), instead.

By default, a radio button will become checked on click, so you don't need to reiterate this default behavior.

I have also updated the code to respond when an input's value changes, as opposed to when the document is clicked and the target was the input.  It is a little lighter performance-wise to listen for the more limited scope than the broader one you had.  The approach that you used used to be referred to as a "live" listener in jQuery and is more appropriate for when JS is adding and removing elements that you're listening for on the page; in your case, PHP is rendering them, so we don't need it.

Additionally, jQuery selectors require a `#` to indicate id, a `.` to indicate class, and without these selectors, it assumes it is a tag.  See below where I am appending a `#` to select the a with the id.

```js
// This is listening for any radio buttons who were clicked, instead of any clicks on the document (it's a little more efficient)
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {

  // get the other radio buttons in this group
  var $group = $('input[name=' + $(this).attr('name') + ']');

  // Go through the group and if the input is checked, add the class to the corresponding element, otherwise, remove it
  $group.each(function() {
    var id_radio = "#" + $(this).attr('value');
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(id_radio).addClass("radio-is-checked");
    } else {
      $(id_radio).removeClass("radio-is-checked");
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.radio-is-checked {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="uk-text-primary uk-text-bold"><u> General Message </u>
</p>
<table class="uk-table uk-border-rounded uk-grid-width-* uk-panel-box uk-text-justify" border="1">
  <!--create top table -->
  <tr>
    <!--tr defines a row -->
    <!-- define row 1 -->
    <th class="uk-width-1-10">Recipient</th>
    <!-- th defines a header cell-->
    <th class="uk-width-1-3">Message</th>
    <th class="uk-width-1-10">Action</th>
    <th class="uk-width-1-10">Default message</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- row 2 : display results onwards and creates dynamically -->
  <!-- input fields at the bottom -->

  <tr>
    <td>$row_msg['user']</td>
    <td>$row_msg['message']</td>
    <!-- Since the radio in this row is checked by default, also apply the corresponding class -->
    <td><a href="#" id="one" class="delete_button uk-text-danger radio-is-checked">Delete</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class='class_radio3' type='radio' name='name_radio2' value='one' checked />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$row_msg['user']</td>
    <td>$row_msg['message']</td>
    <td><a href="#" id="two" class="delete_button uk-text-danger">Delete</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class='class_radio3' type='radio' name='name_radio2' value='two' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$row_msg['user']</td>
    <td>$row_msg['message']</td>
    <td><a href="#" id="three" class="delete_button uk-text-danger">Delete</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class='class_radio3' type='radio' name='name_radio2' value='three' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thirdly, the "default" behavior of a radio button is to become checked.  By doing `e.preventDefault` you're cancelling that default behavior, so it doesn't become checked!

Comment: is `name` and `class` the same thing? as i assume it would be as its like grouping them together under a same category

Comment: no, class is used for styles, and maybe as a selector in JS.  name is for form elements, on submission of the form, it becomes a "key" in the submitted object.  However, I think I misunderstood your question. Will update in a second.

Comment: @peekaboo please see my updates.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: hmm i see, but it seems that with your code when i click a different radio button, the new radio button is now checked however the previous entry still remains as checked

Answer (score 0):

Try This
HTML

```
  if($row_msg['user']=='General'){
 echo "<td>"."<input id='$row_msg_id' class='class_radio3' type='radio' name='name_radio2' value='$row_msg_id' />"."</td>";

                        }
```

JS

```
var id_radio=$(this).attr('id');
  $('#' + id_radio).prop('checked',true);
```

Comment: then use id="radio_".$row_msg_id     and     $('#radio_' + id_radio).prop('checked',true);  please solve syntax error

Comment: just tried your method, doesnt work and you made a syntax mistake should be `id='radio_$row_msg_id'

Answer (score 0):

Check the below,

You can use **attr** like below but i would recommend use **[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**

```js
function chk(element) {
  
  $(element).attr("checked", "checked");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="age">10</label>
<input type="radio" name="age" value="10" onclick="chk(this);" />
<label for="age">15</label>
<input type="radio" name="age" value="15" onclick="chk(this);" />
```